# React Font Awesome, how to use additional classes like 'fa-fw'

Tags: reactjs, font-awesome

I am using React-FontAwesome and If I import Font Awesome like this
`<FontAwesomeIcon icon={['far', calendar]}/>`, and if I need to add spacing using class "fa-fw", how can I do that?

https://codesandbox.io/s/40v5jk6no7

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not sure what are you trying to do but I assume that you are trying to add extra class name. If so use `className` :

```
<FontAwesomeIcon className="fa-fw" icon="calendar" title="magic" />
```

It will produce this `class` attribute:

```
<svg class="svg-inline--fa far-calendar fa-w-14 fa-fw" ...
```

Answer (score 3):

In current version, you can add fixedWidth like this:

```
<FontAwesomeIcon icon="spinner" fixedWidth />
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me using React Individual Import

```
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import { faXmark } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'

<FontAwesomeIcon icon={faXmark} beat size="2xl" className="fa-fw" />

// or

<FontAwesomeIcon icon={faXmark} size="2xl" beat fixedWidth  />
```